# Copying only the values of a list and not the container itself

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to create a nested list of lists and want to be able to manipulate single elements in the list. I have populated the list with zeros and want to be able to change them to some other value by indexing each element.

Every time I assign a value to an element the entire row gets assigned the new value, instead of just the one element.

Is there a way to get around this without using numppy arrays?

```
# Expected output:
[[0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,5,0],
[0,0,0,0,0]]

# Actual output:
[[0,0,0,5,0],
[0,0,0,5,0],
[0,0,0,5,0]]
```

I have tried slicing the list to reference the values using [:], I've tried deep copy, I have tried copy_list = list(org_list) but nothing works.

```
sample_list = [0]*5
sample_list = [sample_list]*3

copy_sample_list = copy.deepcopy(sample_list)
copy_sample_list = sample_list[:]
copy_sample_list = list(sample_list)
copy_sample_list[1][3] = 5

copy_sample_list
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `[[0]*5]*3` denotes a reference to the list of `[0]*5`, so when you modify a value, the entire list will be changed.

try this code:

```
sample_list = [[0]*5 for _ in range(3)]
copy_sample_list = sample_list.copy() 
copy_sample_list[1][3] = 5
```

output:

```
[[0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,5,0],
[0,0,0,0,0]]
```